# why does "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" causing build errors for my expo project?

Tags: expo, onesignal

I have these 2 libraries installed on my expo project:

```
    "onesignal-expo-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.2",
```

When I build my app with eas, it crashes and gives me this message:

```
2023-11-02 17:14:46.173 xcodebuild[4915:14212] warning:  The file reference for "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" is a member of multiple groups ("Pods" and ""); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
```

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: show me your Xcode app group signing and capabilities in xcode

Comment: or try with this CMD expo prebuild --platform ios --clean

Comment: no that didnt work, unfortunately. And im using react native not xcode.

Comment: react-native or expo bro, because in react native u can use Xcode

Comment: Sorry, its all expo and managed

Comment: You need to eject your expo